# Show div in template depending on the input parameter type

Tags: angular, typescript

My situation looks like that: I have a class hierarchy:

[image]

In the Angular App I have a Component, which has a process as input:

```
    @Input() currentProcess: Process
```

Depending on the concrete type of this process (either ProjectProcess or EmployeeProcess) I want to show another div in the template. 
Of course I can do that by checking the variable with instanceof and set a boolen variable and check it with *ngIf in the template - but I don't feel comfortable with that. Is this really the only way or are there better solutions?

Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it clean, use getters :

```
get isProjectProcess() { return this.currentProcess instanceof ProjectProcess; }
get isEmployeeProcess() { return this.currentProcess instanceof EmployeeProcess; }
```

The advantage of this solution is that your boolean values will change at each lifecycle, avoiding you the need of implementing `onChanges`

Comment: I agree 100%.  Use your Angular LifeCycle functions to handle this and do the logic in your component controller.  This makes it more testable and reliable.  And keeps the template more readable. A lot of ..ables